# Python 3 IPv6 Multicast

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipv6, multicast

I am trying to design a straightforward client/server pair for IPv6 multicast communication in Python. The code I have so far seems conforms to examples I've seen online, but my server never receives data.

I see the subscription in `ip maddr show` and `netstat -g`. tcpdump shows: `10:13:36.913546 IP6 (flowlabel 0x77fe8, hlim 5, next-header UDP (17) payload length: 20) **omitted** > ff16::fe.commplex-main: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 12`

The client and server are connected to the same switch and the IPv6 unicast addresses are in the same subnet (they can ping eachother).

**Server**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
import struct

local_addr = ::
mcast_addr = "ff16::fe"
mcast_port = 5000
ifn = "eno1"

# Create socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)

# Set multicast interface
ifi = socket.if_nametoindex(ifn)
ifis = struct.pack("I", ifi)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_MULTICAST_IF, ifis)

# Set multicast group to join
group = socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, mcast_addr) + ifis
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_JOIN_GROUP, group)

sock_addr = socket.getaddrinfo(local_addr, mcast_port, socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)[0][4]
sock.bind(sock_addr)

cmd = ""
while True:
    data, src = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print("From " + str(src) + ": " + data.decode())
```

**Client**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
import struct

message = "Hello world!"
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock_addr = socket.getaddrinfo("ff16::fe", 5000, socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)[0][4]

ttl = struct.pack('i', 5)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS, ttl)

sock.sendto(message.encode(), sock_addr)
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the client and server on the same network? Multicast packets cannot be routed over the Internet.

Comment: The client and server are on the same network.

Comment: "_The client and server are on the same network._" Then you should use the Link-Local scope: `ff12::fe`. You still seem to have incorrectly caclulated the UDP checksum. "_The key difference between UDP usage with IPv4 and IPv6 is that RFC 2460 mandates use of a calculated UDP checksum, i.e., a non-zero value, due to the lack of an IPv6 header checksum. The inclusion of the pseudo-header in the checksum computation provides a statistical check that datagrams have been delivered to the intended IPv6 destination node. Algorithms for checksum computation are described in [RFC1071]._"

Comment: Should an unassigned scope work just as well as the link-local scope in this scenario? As far as the UDP checksum is concerned, what else in my code do I need to do for this?

Comment: According to the RFC, you should be able to use an unassigned scope, but I wouldn't because it may get redefined at some point, For example, until this RFC, Realm-Local was unassigned, and now you can get into trouble trying to use that scope. Admin-Local is pretty common for your own use.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the future. For the purposes of this, I'm just trying to get a quick test done, nothing production/long-term.

Comment: Well, your OSes may not support an unassigned scope. You should use an assigned scope. If they are on the same network, on the same switch, as you hve indicated, then you should probably use the Link-Local scope.

Comment: You could also start with trying to do this on a single host with the Interface-Local scope, which is designed for multicast loopback inside the same host. If you get that working, then move it out to the Link-Local scope and try to get to another host on the same network.

Comment: That makes sense. Trying on the same host, still couldn't get `ff12::fe` or `ff11::fe` to work. Seems that I'm missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to all the other good advice: you bind the socket on the server to the link local address. This will filter incoming packets so that only packets with that destination address reach your code. Packets addressed to the multicast address will be dropped. Try binding to :: and make sure that works before moving on to something more complex.

Comment: Changed it to ::, still no dice. Trace on the server machine sees nothing, sending machine: `10:13:36.913546 IP6 (flowlabel 0x77fe8, hlim 5, next-header UDP (17) payload length: 20) **omitted** > ff16::fe.commplex-main: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 12` The checksum seems to be OK now for some reason... I'm going to add more details about the network setup to the post.

Comment: This was likely an issue with the code as well. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `"ff10::` as an IPv6 multicast address. The scope, `0`, you are using in that address is reserved. There are multiple RFCs to consider for IPv6 multicast, which uses flags and scopes. For example, scope `1` is the Interface-Local Scope, and traffic sent to a group with that scope will not leave the local interface on the sending host.

See [*RFC 7346, IPv6 Multicast Address Scopes*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7346) for the most current scopes:

> 2. Definition of IPv6 Multicast Address Scopes (Updates RFC 4291)
>
> The following table updates the definitions in [RFC4291]:
>
> ```
>     +------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
>     | scop | NAME                     | REFERENCE               |
>     +------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
>     |  0   | Reserved                 | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  1   | Interface-Local scope    | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  2   | Link-Local scope         | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  3   | Realm-Local scope        | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  4   | Admin-Local scope        | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  5   | Site-Local scope         | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  6   | Unassigned               |                         |
>     |  7   | Unassigned               |                         |
>     |  8   | Organization-Local scope | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  9   | Unassigned               |                         |
>     |  A   | Unassigned               |                         |
>     |  B   | Unassigned               |                         |
>     |  C   | Unassigned               |                         |
>     |  D   | Unassigned               |                         |
>     |  E   | Global scope             | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     |  F   | Reserved                 | [RFC4291], RFC 7346     |
>     +------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
> ```

---

**Edit:**

Based on your change to the original question, you are not correctly calculating the UDP checksum, which is optional for IPv4, but required for IPv6.

Also, because you are making up your own multicast address (not an IANA assigned address), you should also go back to using the `T` flag as `1`:

> T = 0 indicates a permanently-assigned ("well-known") multicast
> address, assigned by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA).
>
> T = 1 indicates a non-permanently-assigned ("transient" or
> "dynamically" assigned) multicast address.

---

**Edit 2:**

By the way, you cannot use the zero address in IPv6 multicast:

> Reserved Multicast Addresses:
> `FF00:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF01:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF02:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF03:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF04:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF05:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF06:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF07:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF08:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF09:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF0A:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF0B:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF0C:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF0D:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF0E:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`
> `FF0F:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`

It sounds like you really, really need to study the RFCs before trying to use IPv6 multicast.

Comment: That seems to have allowed the program to start sending the packets, however, the server is still not receiving it. tcpdump with -vv shows: `> ff06::.5000: [bad udp cksum 0xb590 -> 0xf470!] UDP, length 12`, I have updated the question, thanks for the catch.

Comment: Again, thanks, I've modified my code to use a proper multicast address. The question is where is the udp checksum going wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't see where it is being calculated.

Comment: The checksum doesn't seem to be an issue anymore

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the multicast interface in the client as well. Both the client and server had a dummy interface and a VLAN aware interface that were operational (design of the network drivers I can't get into. I set the interfaces on both to be the VLAN aware interface.

**On the client:**

```
# Set multicast interface
ifi = socket.if_nametoindex(ifn)
ifis = struct.pack("I", ifi)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_MULTICAST_IF, ifis)
```